# TypeScript - How to use array map to an ES 6 Map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an array of key value objects:

```
const data = [
    {key: "object1", value: "data1"},
    {key: "object2", value: "data2"},
    {key: "object3", value: "data3"},
]

const mappedData = data.map(x => [x.key, x.value]);

const ES6Map = new Map<string, string>(mappedData.values())
```

How do I convert it to ES 6 map? It works in JavaScript but TypeScript will complain. Here I got the error of `Argument of type 'IterableIterator<string[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[string, string]>'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'IterableIterator<string[]>'.`

Comment: Just remove the `.values()` call

Comment: then it gets `Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[string, string]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, string]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]'.`

Comment: The problem is in your type declarations. I don't know typescript, but if type declaration is optional, why not just do `const ES6Map = new Map(mappedData)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to do `type assertion` and tell typescript that your `mappedData` is of type `Array<[string,string]>` instead of `string[][]` which is a sub type for `Array<[any,any]>` as needed by `Map` constructor.

**Do**

```
const mappedData = data.map(x => [x.key, x.value] as [string, string]);
```

**instead of**

```
const mappedData = data.map(x => [x.key, x.value]);
```

**and also**

drop the `values()` call as pointed out in comments.

Comment: What is the type of `x` in those examples?